# Disable login route if a user is logged in with Hapi.js

Tags: hapi.js

Basically I have a login/register landing page of my app. After a user logs in or registers I don't want them to be able to access this route anymore. I'm not sure how to achieve this with Hapi.js. The login page doesn't use any auth strategies so it has no idea if a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach I normally use for this is not disabling the route per se, but redirecting logged-in users away from the login route.

As you point out correctly your login route currently doesn't know whether a user is logged in if it has no auth strategy configured. The solution is to *add* an auth strategy to the login route, but using the **try** mode. This means the handler will be executed regardless of whether auth was successful. The trick is that you can then check if the user is authenticated (by inspecting the value of `request.auth.isAuthenticated`) or not and react accordingly.

So your route might look like this:

```
server.route({
    config: {
        auth: {
            strategy: 'session',
            mode: 'try'
        }
    },
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/login',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            return reply.redirect('/');        // user is logged-in send 'em away
        }

        return reply.view('login');            // do the login thing
    }
});
```

Another approach with the same result is to set your auth strategy on **try** mode as the default for all routes:

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', 'try', {     
    password: 'password-that-is-longer-than-32-chars',
    isSecure: true
});
```

Notice that third argument `try`. With this approach you don't need to add any auth config to the route itself because it will try this strategy by default. According to the [`server.auth.strategy`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverauthstrategyname-scheme-mode-options) docs:

> `mode` - if true, the scheme is automatically assigned as a required strategy to any route without an auth config. Can only be assigned to a single server strategy. Value must be true (which is the same as 'required') or a valid authentication mode ('required', 'optional', 'try'). Defaults to false.

There's some more info about modes in the [Authentication tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth#mode) on the hapi site.

Comment: Great answer, I don't know how I overlooked the `try` option.